# How to manage hardcoded (VBA) EU date formats in Access when system locality is US

Tags: vba, date, ms-access, ms-access-2013

This is probably a shot in the dark and a little odd but here it goes.. We use an Access 2003 application built by a 3rd party.  It's REALLY horribly written but it calculates behavior measures with tons of scientific research and validation behind it.  This means that we CANNOT modify the application whatsoever.  To be clear we have requested even SMALL changes to be made or to allow us to make and we were denied (changing s to z in wording to be more US format)... based on the grounds that the application is validated and that any change in the application would make the outcome data void per that validation.

The above is important because we CANNOT make any direct changes to any asset inside the MDB file.  Any solutions MUST be a change in the behavior of Access and not a system wide change like changing locality.  Maybe a command line switch or something.

The problem exists that this application was written in a EU country and therefore conforms to EU locality standards hard coded into the VBA.  If there were a command line switch to force EU locality on Access during a single session this would be a great solution... I cannot find one however.

This issue only exposes itself with DATES in this application.

There is an access form that is used whenever date entry is required.  It pops up and requests month by NAME, day and year each it it's own field.  For example a birth date.  Since these fields are filled in separately the VBA code then concatenates them into a date... using EU format only..  Publisher did not take locality into consideration at all. So it places DAY FIRST instead of Month as the US format does.

This is a problem because the date conversions that Microsoft uses apparently doesn't consider EU formatted dates as invalid US dates and will happily convert them..  WRONG 30% of the time.

So what occurs is that a date of May 10, 2000 becomes October 10, 2000 because the date is converted to "DD/MM/YYYY' or 5/10/2000 becomes 10/5/2000.  10/5/2000 is a valid US formatted date but it's not the date entered by the user.  MS considers this a proper date for US, since technically it is,  but does not consider this an error in our date when a number above 12 is placed into the MONTH position.  13/5/2000 is not invalid when MS coverts it.. since there are only 12 months the MS algorithm apparently simply just identifies the date as EU format and converts it to US format... So, 13/5/2000 becomes May 13, 2000 even tho 13 is in a position that should be invalid for US locality but it is turned into the day of month and the 5 is turned into the Month number.  These types of dates come out correct because of this.. 5/13/2000 becomes 13/5/2000 but MS converts it back to 5/13/2000 however 5/10/2000 becomes 10/5/2000 and MS does NOT convert it back to 5/10/2000.

Hope you've followed that so far.

So, as I said, I need a solution that does not involve changing the application (forms, queries, vba or anything else because legally and scientifically we cannot) and does not involve changing system settings like locality.  Any solution needs to affect access only and also only affect it during the use of this single database ... ie: command line switch.

Comment: I think you are out of luck. I can't think of any way of fixing this without code. Access uses the system locality to interpret dates on forms, however any background code should be formatting those dates into the Access SQL standard of  mm/dd/yyyy , and I suspect whoever wrote it is doing that, which is probably actually what's breaking it. 
The safest way is to format all dates as `yyyy/mm/dd ` which is always interpreted correctly regards of local settings. But again that would need code changes.

Comment: First, there's no such thing as a "EU date format". Countries differ. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country -- Second, I would suggest to (a) change locale settings, (b) run application, (c) change locale settings back. Registry files can make that less painful.

Comment: FWIW it's the US date format that's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  We are leaning toward the "out of luck" scenario.  There are alternatives to this application that our organization is unwilling to pursue at this time.. but maybe that's just the route we have to go.  As for EU date format.. maybe i should have stated this was written in Englahd and therefor use DMY instead of MDY.

Answer (score 4):

> *We use an Access 2003 application built by a 3rd party. It's REALLY horribly written but it calculates behavior measures with tons of scientific research and validation behind it. This means that we CANNOT modify the application whatsoever.*

Not. This means you have a crying need for **unit tests**. Make a backup copy, and then cover all the complex scientific functions with a thorough test suite ([Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) could help with that).

Once you have a proper test suite with green tests that thoroughly validate that the code does what it's supposed to be doing, you are free to make all the changes you want, including refactoring the complex logic if you need to: if you've covered all execution paths then every test will either remain green meaning the code still does what it was written for, or some will turn red meaning you made a change that modified something that shouldn't have been modified. With each test making one single assertion, a single red test means you know *exactly* what broke, where, and how.

"The application is validated" - I call BS. If there are no unit tests, there is no validation. Someone ran the code, tried various inputs, and rubberstamped [APPROVED]. That's no validation. Heck, that's no testing. Not *useful* testing anyway. Useful tests *specifically* **enable** making changes to an application, **because** they validate that the code does what it does the way it should do it.

Read [Working Effectively With Legacy Code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/122014/68834), by Michael C. Feathers. Locking down a critical application that's badly written just because it's critical, is outright dumb.

If you can't add proper unit tests, and can't modify anything whatsoever, then don't bother reporting bugs: that "validated" program is treating its bugs as features - it works that [broken] way because that's how it is and there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: All fine and dandy but the application is a 3rd party copyrighted application and we cannot just simply make these changes without permission.  So while this is great information it simply does not apply.  They are unable to make modifications for us and deny requests for us to make modifications.

Comment: Buy a developer license for it, and fix it yourself if they won't. That 3rd party is doomed if they can't fix their bugs and don't let their clients fix them either. Your only hope is [a VM set up with a locale that works with the code in its current broken state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44951318/1188513).

Comment: I am with you.  Assuming they have any license at all... which they technically do.. but it's unacceptable... contract is an email only. license is per submission of the data... and we are forced to rewrite the entire application from scratch using their methods on a web platform...  we would not be allowed to simply edit the code in the application they provided. As I opened with, this is a "REALLY horrible" application.. and that extends to the whole gambit.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: Hmm, so they have a public web API? That could be a very fun greenfield project, to rewrite the whole thing in C# and working off an actual database server e.g. SQL Server (vs a desktop database e.g. MS-Access). If you don't have an IT department to do this, I'm sure you can find a good contractor that can write actual code *with unit tests*, and leave you with a half-decent code base that you can modify at will.

Comment: No, they do not have a public web API.  They have a paper version and this access application written, probably, by someones cousin who thought he knew alot about computers and learned it all on the fly...  It would be a nice project to rewrite and yes, we do have an IT department included 4 developers...of which I am one of... but I report to the Director of IT and he reports to the CFO and I get to do what those 2 say...  Licensing is basically, "hey you go rewrite the whole thing and then pay us for doing so and no you can't reuse anything we already wrote."

Comment: Sometimes paying for the right to rewrite *is* worth it. I got my boss to pay for a 3rd-party T-SQL script that, last time it ran, ran for over 36 hours, locking itself to death and missing the most basic/glaringly obvious indexes. I rewrote it and now it runs in under 20 seconds. If that app really *is* critical, then it should be *critical* that it works as intended. Shouldn't be a very tough case to argue with the CFO ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can try running Access using a locale emulator such as [this one](https://github.com/xupefei/Locale-Emulator) or [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppLocale) (last one is no longer supported). Also, you can run it inside a VM, or on a different computer/server with correct locale settings and allow users to remotely connect to it.

As you can neither modify the database nor the locale settings, I don't see any other options.

Comment: These have interesting promise...   but the other caveat is that this application is published via Citrix and runs on thin clients.  We would need to invest in a server license for citrix just to run one application.   I will keep this in the discussion when I speak to the team.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you can't modify the database, can't (temporarily) modify the locale settings, and can't install any extra programs, there's not much that you can do, so there's not much for us to help you with. Good luck with the project.

Answer (score 1):

Date values carries no format - but:

> It pops up and requests month by NAME, day and year each it it's own
>   field.

and - assuming month is a combobox returning the month number - these are used to build the date like:

```
EnteredDate = DateSerial(Me!Year.Value, Me!Month.Value, Me!Day.Value)
```

the date will be correct.

So the application probably uses some phony string to date handling; if this is the case, and you cannot alter the form and the method, there is nothing to do.

This is trivial stuff, so you should address the issue to the developer.

Comment: While you are correct that this _should_ be fixed by the dev, you may note in the OP that there is quite a bit of program validation that would be required for even a simple change like this, and the dev seems unwilling to undertake the effort. Therefore, this unfortunately does _not_  answer the question as asked.

Comment: Yes, you may be forced to compromise ... Erik's suggested method could prove useful.

Comment: Their code simply sets a string value to DAY + "/" + MONTH _ "/" + YEAR then throws it in the table.  We not only are unwilling to validate an entire application over this date change but we have been denied changes by the developer.  We are unwilling to break the license agreement even over this simple change.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: Oh. That will fail if MONTH is numeric. DateSerial is here to avoid such cases.